# Methods of writing large amount of data and formulas for that data in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a mini html5 game and I've stumbled upon an interesting problem, for me at least. And that's how to write the formulas for spells. For example:

`SpellOne = baseDmg + level*dmgPerLvl + ratio*someStat;`

that would be only one formula, but my point is, obviously if I write it like that it will calculate the damage from the start and SpellOne will become just a number, not a formula anymore. I can only think of two ways to do it, please lend me your help and give me any advice you have on this.

```
SpellOne.baseDmg = 50;
SpellOne.dmgPerLvl = 30;
SpellOne.baseCd = 15; // cd = spell cooldown
SpellOne.CdPerLvl = 2; // cd decreases by 2 every level
SpellOne.baseCost = 50; // mana or whatever resource
SPellOne.CostPerLvl = 20; // increases by 20 each level
```

and then once the player uses the spell it calculates the latest update:

```
SpellOneDamage = baseDmg + level*dmgPerLevel
```

The other method I have is something that came to me recently. I have around 100 heroes, each with like a dozen stats and then several spells that also have their own stats. But only 1 or 2 heroes will be loaded ever at one time, so am I wasting 'resources' or adding to many useless variables to the dom tree? Since only 1% of them are being used? Which made me think of the following solution:

Make each hero one long function, and when a person changes their hero, it runs the function and for example the 'currentHero' variable takes upon itself ALL the stats from the hero, spell stats too. So when the person changes heroes again, all that's really happening is 'currentHero' variable changes its values and thus you wont have to load ALL the hero stats pointlessly? It only loads a hero when selected. Any suggestions you guys have are greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just make a function that calculates the damage when needed?

Comment: Variables aren't in the DOM TREE, they're in memory.

Comment: Thank you Diodeus, sorry for my ignorance. Would you happen to know if this is only client side? Or would it also take more memory for the server it's being loaded on? If true then there really would be no point loading all the hero data, even if it's under a single object. And thanks @Juhana, but that's what I said with the 'calculate the damage when he uses the spell'? Unless I misunderstood what you said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're recalculating the damage for each spell many times per second, why not just make it a function and add it to the prototype of your character?

```
Character.prototype.getSpellDamage = function(name) {
    var spell = Spells[name];

    return spell.baseDamage
           + this.level * spell.damagePerLevel
           + spell.ratio * this[spell.someStat];
}
```

Now, you can just store the spells in a simple object:

```
var Spells = {
    'foo bar': {
        baseDamage: 40,
        damagePerLevel: 20,
        ratio: 0.5,
        someStat: 'foo'
    },
    ...
};
```

Comment: I'm always asking myself if it's the spell's reponsability to calculate it's damage by implementing a `calculateDamage(player) {}` function or the opposite. I guess here that the spell would have to know more about the player than the player has to know about the spell, so there would be "less coupling" with your approach, however it makes sense to me that the spell knows how to compute it's own damage. What do you think?

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write it out and explain it to me, I really appreciate it. Would you say it's better to calculate the damage on spell use? or whenever a stat that can change the damage of the spell gets changed? I only ask because, I'm wodnering if it's better to update the damage of the spell a little more often but not during critical moments like when using a spell compared to leveling up, changing items, receiving a buff etc?

Comment: @HateNames: Unless `getSpellDamage` is a bottleneck, don't waste your time optimizing it.

Comment: @HateNames, Unless you have performance issues, I wouldn't try to over optimize by avoiding the re-computation of the damage everytime. However, it would be definitely more efficient to cache the spell damage and refresh it when something in the formula changes.

Comment: @Blender, would you mind having a look at my question? Thanks!

Comment: @plalx: What question?

Comment: @Blender, The first comment I made on your answer, starting by "I'm always asking..." ;)

Comment: @plalx: It's pretty ambiguous here, I agree. `Player.calculateDamage` would make more sense, as the weapon is being used by the player, not the player being used by the weapon.